# group array with timestamps

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I got a array of objects that have timestamps in them - looks like the following - I'm using react so I got no problem rendering it - I just don't understand how to group and sort it like this.

```
const data = [ 
{ id: 0, timeStamp: 1619627889000, title: 'First One' },
{ id: 0, timeStamp: 1619368689000, title: 'Second One' },
{ id: 0, timeStamp: 1619195889000, title: 'Third One' },
{ id: 0, timeStamp: 1619627889000, title: 'Fourth One' },
{ id: 0, timeStamp: 1619195889000, title: 'Fifth One' },
]
```

I want to make sure that if the timestamp is older than 7 days don't add it to the array, I just want the data between now and -7 days so a week.

I want to group the array above if the timestamp is in the same day together so the output will be something like

```
Wed Apr 28

title: First One

title: Fourth one


Sun Apr 25

title: Second one

Fri Apr 23

title:  Third one

title: Fifth one
```

Comment: What's the specific issue, grouping by day? Seems like that would just be converting the timestamp to a date and getting the respective days, yes?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is not a website where people write code for you so that you don't have to. If you need help debugging code that you have written, you must post a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and explain the specific problem with your code.

Comment: @DaveNewton - Yeah basically grouping it day by day or whatever the timestamp corresponds etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple arithmetic to calculate the day. There are 86400000ms (8.64e7) in a day (javascript discounts leap seconds), so simply dividing and rounding down will yield the day since the Unix epoch. Here using the result in a basic 'groupBy' `reduce()` call.

```js
const
  data = [{ id: 0, timeStamp: 1619627889000, title: 'First One' }, { id: 1, timeStamp: 1619368689000, title: 'Second One' }, { id: 2, timeStamp: 1619195889000, title: 'Third One' }, { id: 3, timeStamp: 1619627889000, title: 'Fourth One' }, { id: 4, timeStamp: 1619195889000, title: 'Fifth One' },],
  
  grouped = Object.values(
    data.reduce((a, o) => {
      const day = Math.floor(o.timeStamp / 8.64e7);
      (a[day] ??= []).push({ ...o });
      return a;
    }, {}));

console.log(grouped)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

In order to check if an element is within the last 7 days you can simply calculate the day of `today` in the same way as you did for each timestamp and compare the difference.

```
const today = Math.floor(Date.now() / 8.64e7);
```

```js
const
  data = [{ id: 0, timeStamp: 1619627889000, title: 'First One' }, { id: 1, timeStamp: 1619368689000, title: 'Second One' }, { id: 2, timeStamp: 1619195889000, title: 'Third One' }, { id: 3, timeStamp: 1619627889000, title: 'Fourth One' }, { id: 4, timeStamp: 1619195889000, title: 'Fifth One' },],

  today = Math.floor(Date.now() / 8.64e7),

  grouped = Object.values(
    data.reduce((a, o) => {
      const day = Math.floor(o.timeStamp / 8.64e7);
      // check if timestamp is within the last 7 days.
      if ((today - day) < 7) {
        (a[day] ??= []).push({ ...o });
      }
      return a;
    }, {}));

console.log(grouped)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

As for the use of `.reduce()` – in this use case it is simply a concise implementation of a `for...of` loop combined with an accumulator and can be rewritten as such.

```js
const data = [{ id: 0, timeStamp: 1619627889000, title: 'First One' }, { id: 1, timeStamp: 1619368689000, title: 'Second One' }, { id: 2, timeStamp: 1619195889000, title: 'Third One' }, { id: 3, timeStamp: 1619627889000, title: 'Fourth One' }, { id: 4, timeStamp: 1619195889000, title: 'Fifth One' },];

const grouped = {};
for (const o of data) {
  const day = Math.floor(o.timeStamp / 8.64e7);
  (grouped[day] ??= []).push({ ...o });
}

console.log(Object.values(grouped));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Fantastic this! Thanks, do you care to explain how we use reduce to actually get this to 'group by'? Cause I was trying all sorts of things but really don't understand why reduce is so useful in such case... Thanks again

Comment: Also - how would check if the timestamp is between now and minus 7 days? so you only want the group by to show between now and - 7 days

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use-case for [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), something like this:

```js
const data = [{
    id: 0,
    timeStamp: 1619627889000,
    title: 'First One'
  },
  {
    id: 0,
    timeStamp: 1619368689000,
    title: 'Second One'
  },
  {
    id: 0,
    timeStamp: 1619195889000,
    title: 'Third One'
  },
  {
    id: 0,
    timeStamp: 1619627889000,
    title: 'Fourth One'
  },
  {
    id: 0,
    timeStamp: 1619195889000,
    title: 'Fifth One'
  },
];

// Group the data based on the timestamp
const groups = data.reduce((map, el) => {
  map.set(el.timeStamp, map.get(el.timeStamp) ? map.get(el.timeStamp).concat(el.title) : [el.title]);

  return map;
}, new Map());

// Iterate over the map and output the data, formatted as you like:
for (entry of groups) {
  const [key, val] = entry;

  console.log(new Date(key).toLocaleDateString('en'));

  val.forEach(title => console.dir(`Title: ${title}`));

  console.log("\n");
}
```

If you wanted to group by the date instead of the actual timestamp, simply covert the timestamp to a date first and use that as the Map key, for example:

```js
const data = [{
    id: 0,
    timeStamp: 1619627889000,
    title: 'First One'
  },
  {
    id: 0,
    timeStamp: 1619368689000,
    title: 'Second One'
  },
  {
    id: 0,
    timeStamp: 1619195889000,
    title: 'Third One'
  },
  {
    id: 0,
    timeStamp: 1619627889000,
    title: 'Fourth One'
  },
  {
    id: 0,
    timeStamp: 1619195889000,
    title: 'Fifth One'
  },
];

// Group the data based on the timestamp
const groups = data.reduce((map, el) => {
  const dateKey = new Date(el.timeStamp).toLocaleDateString('en')
  map.set(dateKey, map.get(dateKey) ? map.get(dateKey).concat(el.title) : [el.title]);

  return map;
}, new Map());

// Iterate over the map and output the data, formatted as you like:
for (entry of groups) {
  const [key, val] = entry;

  console.log(key);

  val.forEach(title => console.dir(`Title: ${title}`));

  console.log("\n");
}
```

Comment: Cheers Tom really good solution, however, lets say I was to add a timestamp with the same day but different hour, it still creates a new date entry and not underneath the already existing group?

Comment: Hi @nikomannelig, yes that is correct. In that situation you would want to convert the timestamp to a date and use that as the Map key instead of using the timestamp itself like I did in my example. You would simply disregard the time portion of the timestamp when converting it to a date. I added a second code example showing this (it's not too different than the original example).

Comment: Seems like its worked - made a function to format the timestamp and replace the (el.timeStamp) to convert(el.timeStamp) etc - Thank you